# EPOLLRDHUP not reliable

Tags: tcp, epoll

I'm using non-blocking read/writes over a client-server TCP connection with `epoll_wait`.

Problem is, I can't reliably detect 'peer closed connection' event using the `EPOLLRDHUP` flag. It often happens that the flag is not set. The client uses `close()` and the server, most of the time, receives, from `epoll_wait`, an `EPOLLIN | EPOLLRDHUP` event. Reading yields zero bytes, as expected. Sometimes, though, only `EPOLLIN` comes, yielding zero bytes.

Investigation using `tcpdump` shows that normal shutdown occurs as far as I can tell. I see a `Flags [F.], Flags [F.], Flags [.]` sequence of events, which should correspond to FIN, FIN and ACK. `SO_LINGER` is nowhere used.

I considered handling 'peer closed' on zero-byte read, however, there is the possibility that you get an `EPOLLIN | EPOLLRDHUP` event with non-zero bytes available, when the peer sends & immediately closes the connection - case in which I need to base myself on the `EPOLLRDHUP`. Suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer this: `EPOLLRDHUP` indeed comes if you continue to poll after receiving a zero-byte read.
So from my experiments it looks like either an `EPOLLIN` with zero-byte read or an `EPOLLRDHUP` are reliable indicators for orderly shutdown, the only trouble was, they are not received together. Sometimes (the case that makes the subject of this question), it happens that EPOLLIN is received, yielding zero bytes (connection terminated), and on subsequent polling you get to see the `EPOLLRDHUP`. Other times, it's vice-versa: you get the `EPOLLRDHUP` together with an `EPOLLIN` that signals actual bytes to be read. Then, on subsequent reads, you get zero bytes.

Comment: So the upshot is that if the `EPOLLIN | EPOLLRDHUP` combination is received, which signals that that there are non-zero bytes to read and the connection was terminated, just keep reading until you get 0 bytes -- and that will signal shutdown. In other words, when you read 0, you're done -- so it suffices just to check for `EPOLLIN`?

Comment: If you get `EPOLLIN | EPOLLRDHUP` and then you read() or recv() into a buffer of sized X, but get back _less than_ X bytes, then `EPOLLRDHUP` can be leveraged to indicate EOF without an additional read.  If you get back X bytes, then read again until you get less than X bytes.  Even if the connection has closed on the remote side, there might still be data pending in local kernel socket buffers that you might not have read yet.